# Get new profile cover with sdk

Tags: facebook-graph-api, cover

Is it possible to get and to change the new porfile cover (mine or my friends' profil cover) with the sdk php or JS ?

Comment: you mean the users profile picture? no, this is not possible.

Comment: I think he's not talking about the normal profile picture, but the new big picture at the top of the profil Timeline. But I didn't see nothing about that for now… Hope it'll be possible in the future.

Comment: Well, based on the current convention. I guess retrieving the cover will be available soon. Maybe extending the `user_id/picture` method like `user_id/picture?type=cover` or creating a new one `user_id/cover`. Anyway, I don't *think* you'll be able to change it programatically.

Comment: Thanks you for yours responses, for this moment, I think too it's impossible.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to get the Facebook's [user cover image using the Graph API](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/user/). You have to add 'fields=cover' to the user request. The response is an array of fields id, source, and offset_y. You need an access token for this.

You cannot update the cover photo using the API, only retrieve it.

> http://graph.facebook.com/[USER_ID]?fields=cover

Comment: According to facebook docs linked in this answer (and my tests), an access token is required.

Answer (score 0):

It's still not possible with the current APIs exposed by Facebook.